# Remove namespace from the xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Below is the Input XML that I am trying to convert to another xml without namespace. I tried to remove namespace but it is not working. All the required details are provided below for the request.

```
 <ns1:FieldResponse
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
    <ns1:response>
        <ns1:Elements>
            <ns1:workRequestId>12123</ns1:workRequestId>
        </ns1:Elements>
    </ns1:response>
    <ns1:Status>1232</ns1:Status>
   </ns1:FieldResponse>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <Elements>
        <workRequestId>12123</workRequestId>
    </Elements>
</response>
<Status>1232</Status>
```

Output after the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
    <cmElements>
        <workRequestId>12123</workRequestId>
    </cmElements>
</response>
<Status
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">1232
</Status>
```

XSLT Used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<response>
<Elements>
<workRequestId>
<xsl:value-of   select="/ns1:FieldResponse/ns1:response/ns1:Elements/ns1:workRequestId"/>
</workRequestId>
</Elements>
 
<xsl:for-each select="/ns1:FieldResponse/ns1:response/ns1:fault">
<fault>
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</fault>
</xsl:for-each>
 
</response>
 
<Status>
<xsl:value-of   select="/ns1:FieldResponse/ns1:Status"/>
</Status>
 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that the output is an XML fragment (no single root element), not a well-formed XML document.